# Does visual studio 2013 express(update2) support the development for wp8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I just install visual studio 2013 express(update2)  and mobile sdk for wp
But can not find out where is the option for wp8.
Does visual studio 2013 express(update2)  support development for wp8?
or do I need to download any plugin?

Updated question

[image]

Your comment welcome

Comment: What is the OS that you are running. Needs to be Windows 8 64 bit also which version of visual studio are you running?

Comment: Windows 8.1 64, visual studio 2013 only works on win 8.1. I know vs 2012 can develop app for wp8, but I hope less development tool and hope to do everything for winrt/wp using one tool

Comment: VS2013 works just fine on Windows 7.  I'm using it right now.

Comment: Actually VS 2013 will run on windows 7, you just won't have Windows store and phone development.

Comment: visual studio 2013 express(update2) for windows Does have the option of winstore and wp 8.1 development.

Comment: while Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop does not have the option for winstore and wp 8.1 development, it only can develop win32 app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Here is the [Download Link](http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs) & [System Requirements](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs)

You don't need to `Install any Plugin`, Once you install Visual Studio Express 2013 Update 2 for Windows, you can create Windows Phone 8.1 applications.

EDIT:

You can create Windows Phone 8.1 (New XAML Based API's) like;

[image: Blank Application (Windows Phone)]

You can create Windows Phone 8 & 8.1 (Old Silverlight Based API's) like;

[image: Windows Phone Silverlight]

[image: OS Option]

By creating App with the Second Picture, you will get;

[image: Emulators]

EDIT 2:

I found this [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/br211384.aspx)

[image: 8 SDK]

Comment: but I downloaded and install emulator 8.1 and can not found the emulator 8 on options

Comment: When you install Update 2 for Visual Studio 2013, it lets you create applications for both Windows Phone 8.1 (With New XAML based API's) & Windows Phone 8 & 8.1 (With Old SilverLight API's). Check the Edit.

Comment: I have to install emulator for wp8, vs 2013 express does not include the emulator wp8, it lead me to https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk

Comment: needs to download 'Windows Phone SDK 8.0 Update 3 Emulators' :-(