# Windows phone 8 application creation issues

Tags: templates, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

Recently I have updated to visual studio 2013 update 2 and tried creating windows phone 8.1 application. Everything worked fine.

But it is allowing me to create only windows phone 8.1 application and no more windows phone 8.0 application. It is not asking me to chose between 8.0 or 8.1.

Is there anyway to overcome this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have come across your questions. so i suggest you http://channel9.msdn.com/WindowsPhone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Does visual studio 2013 express(update2) support the development for wp8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557017/does-visual-studio-2013-expressupdate2-support-the-development-for-wp8/24557516#24557516)

Look at this question, it will help you solve your problem, Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 do allow you to create Windows Phone 8.1 (NEW XAML BASED API's) application & Windows Phone 8.1 & 8.0 (OLD SILVERLIGHT BASED API's) application.

> Just go to Visual Studio 2013 -> New Project -> Universal App ->
>   Windows Phone -> Blank Application (Windows Phone Silverlight).

See if this helps.